# How can I go straight to edit mode by choosing selection modes?

Tags: customization

That's basically it,is there a way to configure blender to go straight to edit mode when I choose a selection mode(eg; 1-for vertex,2-for edges or 3-for polygons)?

It may seem silly but I think it's bureaucratic since these shortcurts alone have no real utility.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: The numerical keys outside of numpad in 2.80 actually retain the functionality of previous versions if you have collections(previously layers). You can easily toggle visibility of collections with them. This might be a really useful feature to have easy shortcuts for. It might be worth to consider this.

Comment: I understand these things have a purpose which was previously though and for someone has a utility, yet I think in a rank of priority I can`t imagine a scene in which switching between collections would be more relevant than sparing the time and bureaucracy to access such a simple function.
 
 IMO tthe schortcus could be dynamic when it comes when switching windows, lets say they could have a functionality when in collection screen(can we please change it to explorer hahaha) and another when in 3D aditing viewport.

Comment: You could set up your keymap to work like that - differently in different areas of the UI. I think it is set to work in 3d view like that intentionally with collections. I just mentioned it because I thought the functionality is not immediately obvious, but sure, if you are not going to use it this way, it makes sense to set it up the way it is convenient for you.

Comment: Sure, but do you know how I could do that? coding perhaps? 'Cause i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score -2):

I agree with you - and set up a macro on Belkin Nostromos Keypad.   So I kind of cheated to solve this (and set it up outside of Blender).    I also have been playing with this same macro with "VoiceMacro" to do the same thing.   "Vertex" is programmed to: Press ESC (make sure I'm out of circle select), 
Press Tab, 6 (edit mode)
Press 1, (vertex select)

Comment: It will take me sometime to understand what you said, could you explain it in a more simple way please

Comment: You can use a macro to accomplish this task.   Outside of Blender assign many keystroke sequences to one keypress.   Look up a product called autohotkey.   I use it all the time.

Comment: Here's the link https://www.autohotkey.com/